# Apply XSLT to XML in android (Java)

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt

I need to transform XML in txt with the help of XSLT. While transforming tasks should be group by categories.
I've tried an online transformer, and everything worked, but Android doesn't.
[image: online transformer]

I've got an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TaskInfo>
    <TaskList>
        <Task date="12.11.2022" taskText="1" category="Нет категории"/>
        <Task date="12.11.2022" taskText="2" category="joblnlnl"/>
    </TaskList>
    <CategoryList>
        <Category value="Нет категории"/>
        <Category value="joblnlnl"/>
    </CategoryList>
</TaskInfo>
```

I need to transform it to text with xslt. Also I need to **group tasks by category**, and now (with the xslt below) I'm just trying to print categories, but even this doesn't work.
My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   
    <xsl:output method="text" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/TaskInfo/TaskList">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Task" group-by="@category">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In java code I am using a method:

```
public static boolean createTxtFromXml(String xmlFileName, String xsltFileName,
String resultFileName, String date,
Activity activity)
{
try{
// создание xslt файла
String xslt =
"\<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"\\n" +
"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform%5C%22%3E%5Cn%22 +
"   \\n" +
"\\t\<xsl:output method="text" \\n" +
"\\t\\tomit-xml-declaration="yes"\\n" +
"\\t\\tencoding="UTF-8"/\>\\n" +
"\\t\\t\\n" +
"\\t\<xsl:template match="/TaskInfo/TaskList"\>\\n" +
"\\t\\t\<xsl:for-each-group select="Task" group-by="@category"\>\\n" +
"\\t\\t\\t\<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /\>\\n" +
"\\t\\t\\t\<xsl:text\>
\</xsl:text\>\\n" +
"\\t\\t\</xsl:for-each-group\>\\n" +
"\\t\</xsl:template\>\\n" +
"\\n" +
"\</xsl:stylesheet\>\\n";

        File xslt_file = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), xsltFileName);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(xslt_file, false);
        fw.write(xslt);
        fw.close();
    
        //
        FileInputStream xml_file_istream = activity.openFileInput(xmlFileName);
        FileInputStream xslt_file_istream = activity.openFileInput(xsltFileName);
        FileOutputStream result_file_ostream = activity.openFileOutput(resultFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    
        Source xml_source = new StreamSource(xml_file_istream);
        Source xslt_source = new StreamSource(xslt_file_istream);
    
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt_source);
        transformer.transform(xml_source, new StreamResult(result_file_ostream));
    
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Lab_8_bd", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
```

Expected result in my txt file:

```
Нет категории
joblnlnl
```

But on this string null pointer is returning, so file isn't created:
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt_source);

[image: debugger]

Comment: XSLT 2 or 3 (for-each-group was introduced in XSLT 2) is not supported for most Java platforms/runtimes by the built-in Transformer, that tends to support XSLT 1 only. It is however, possible, to use Saxon HE Java with Android, there is some setting (dex or multidex?) needed to ensure the Android Java compiler can use/grok the library. Whether it plugs into the JAXP Transformer API, even on Android, by simply putting it on the classpath, is something I have never tried, but you can certainly use its s9api API to run XSLT 2/3 with Java code under Android.

Comment: Otherwise, simple grouping in XSLT 1 is possible, even if a little hard to understand, by using Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: After 100 attempts, I thought that xslt 1.0 should be used, but I really hoped that there were other options. Apparently, I still have to deal with this terrible syntax of the first version.

Comment: I have now checked whether adding Saxon HE 11.4 from Maven as a dependency to an Android Studio project makes the JAXP TransformerFactory use Saxon by default. That doesn't seem to be the case so either explicitly create a Saxon `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`, as documented in https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html, or use s9api https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html, if you want to use XSLT 2/3 inside of an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result I changed TXT format to XML. So now I have an XSLT file that groups tasks with a selected date into categories.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"" 
             xslt:indent-amount="3" xmlns:xslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"/> 
             
<xsl:key name="group" match="Task" use="@category"/> 
 
<xsl:template match="TaskInfo/TaskList"> 
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <Tasks> 
        <xsl:attribute name="date"> 
            <xsl:text>17.11.2022</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Task[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('group',@category))]" /> 
    </Tasks> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Task"> 
    <Category> 
       <xsl:attribute name="value"> 
           <xsl:value-of select = "@category"/> 
       </xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:for-each select="key('group',@category)"> 
            <xsl:if test="@date='17.11.2022'">
                <TaskText><xsl:value-of select="@taskText"/></TaskText> 
            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Category> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where 17.11.2022 date can be changed to the selected one.